# Why is Matlab's unifrnd(a,b) so slow?

Tags: matlab, julia, sampling, uniform-distribution

I was doing a simple speed comparison between Matlab and Julia (using the tic, toc command) running a Gibbs sampler with rejection sampling. For Matlab I ran two different versions of the code. One was using the built-in unifrnd(a,b) while the other was drawing uniform random numbers in the interval (a,b) by calling the following function:

```
% Draw a uniform random sample in the interval (a,b)
function f = rand_uniform(a,b)
f = a + rand*(b - a);
end
```

I used the same function as above in the Julia code.

The results from running the code with 1000000 iterations were the following:

**Case 1: Matlab using unifrnd(a,b):**

x_bar = 1.0944

y_bar = 1.1426

Elapsed time is 255.201619 seconds.

**Case 2: Matlab calling rand_uniform(a,b) (function above):**

x_bar =1.0947

y_bar =1.1429

Elapsed time is 38.704601 seconds.

**Case 3: Julia calling rand_uniform(a,b) (function above):**

x_bar = 1.0951446303536603

y_bar = 1.142634615899686

Elapsed time: 3.563854193 seconds

Clearly using unifrnd(a,b) slowed the Matlab code down a lot but the question is why? The density is taken from one of the examples in [Introduction to Applied Bayesian Statistics and Estimation for Social Scientists](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387712642) and if anyone is interested the theoretical mean, mu_x = 1.095 while mu_y = 1.143.

**Case 1: The Matlab code using the built-in unifrnd(a,b) is:**

```
clear;
clc;
tic

% == Setting up matrices and preliminaries == %
d = 1000000;                        % No. of iterations                     
b = d*0.25;                         % Burn-in length. We discard 25% of the sample (not used here)
x = zeros(1,d);
x(1) = -1;
y = zeros(1,d);
y(1) = -1;
m = 25;                             % The constant multiplied on g(x)
count = 0;                          % Counting no. of iterations

% == The Gibbs sampler using rejection sampling == %
for i = 2:d

    % Sample from x|y
    z = 0;
    while z == 0
        u = unifrnd(0,2);           
        if ((2*u+3*y(i-1)+2) > unifrnd(0,2)*m) % Height is (1/(b-a))*m = 0.5*25 = 12.5
            x(i) = u;
            z = 1;
        end
    end

    % Sample from y|x
    z = 0;
    while z == 0
        u = unifrnd(0,2);
        if ((2*x(i)+3*u+2) > unifrnd(0,2)*m)
            y(i) = u;
            z = 1;
        end
    end     
    %count = count+1                 % For counting no. of total draws from m*g(x) 
end

x_bar = mean(x)
y_bar = mean(y)

toc
```

**Case 2: The Matlab code calling rand_uniform(a,b) (function above):**

```
clear;
clc;
tic

% == Setting up matrices and preliminaries == %
d = 1000000;                        % No. of iterations                     
b = d*0.25;                         % Burn-in length. We discard 25% of the sample (not used here)
x = zeros(1,d);
x(1) = -1;
y = zeros(1,d);
y(1) = -1;
m = 25;                             % The constant multiplied on g(x)
count = 0;                          % Counting no. of iterations

% == The Gibbs sampler using rejection sampling == %
for i = 2:d

    % Sample from x|y
    z = 0;
    while z == 0
        u = rand_uniform(0,2);           
        if ((2*u+3*y(i-1)+2) > rand_uniform(0,2)*m) % Height is (1/(b-a))*m = 0.5*25 = 12.5
            x(i) = u;
            z = 1;
        end
    end

    % Sample from y|x
    z = 0;
    while z == 0
        u = rand_uniform(0,2);
        if ((2*x(i)+3*u+2) > rand_uniform(0,2)*m)
            y(i) = u;
            z = 1;
        end
    end     
    %count = count+1                 % For counting no. of total draws from m*g(x) 
end

x_bar = mean(x)
y_bar = mean(y)

toc
```

**Case 3: The Julia code calling rand_uniform(a,b) (function above):**

```
# Gibbs sampling with rejection sampling
tic()

# == Return a uniform random sample from the interval (a, b) == #
function rand_uniform(a, b)
    a + rand()*(b - a)
end

# == Setup and preliminaries == #
d = 1000000                         # No. of iterations
b = d*0.25                          # Burn-in length. We discard 25% of the sample (not used here)
x = zeros(d)
x[1] = -1
y = zeros(d)
y[1] = -1
m = 25

# == The Gibbs sampler using rejection sampling == #
for i in 2:d

  #Sample from y|x
  z = 0
  while z==0
    u = rand_uniform(0,2)
    if ((2*u+3*y[i-1]+2) > rand_uniform(0,2)*m)   #Height is (1/(b-a))*m = 0.5*25 = 12.5
      x[i] = u
      z = 1
    end
  end

  #Sample from x|y
  z = 0
    while z == 0
        u = rand_uniform(0,2)
        if ((2*x[i]+3*u+2) > rand_uniform(0,2)*m)
            y[i] = u
            z = 1
        end
    end
end

println("x_bar = ", mean(x))
println("y_bar = ", mean(y))

toc()
```

Comment: For further comparison, MATLAB R2016a runs Case 2 in 1.5 seconds.

Comment: Great info! I ran the code in Matlab R2014b but I have access to R2015b which seems to be using the same JIT as R2016a. I will download and try it at some point in the week. For Julia I was running 0.4.5.

Comment: Please read the Julia performance tips: Wrap the Julia code in a function, run it once and then time it with @time. This should give a (much)  faster time, and show you if it is allocating too much memory (which indicates a type instability)

Comment: Profiling the code on my R2015a install shows that only about 23% of `unifrnd`'s runtime is used to calculate the random sample with the other portions devoted to error checking, scaling, etc. (and a whopping 35% on some weird size checking function that doesn't seem to do anything). Albeit I'm showing a 3.2:1 time ratio opposed to your 6.6:1.  As for why Julia is faster, *shrug*.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! When I wrapped the entire code in a function the tic()-toc() gave me: 1.389549004 seconds while @time() gave me 0.813527 seconds in the first run. The second to sixth times I ran the code I got around 0.34142948 seconds from tic()-toc() and @time() gave me around 0.329790 seconds. However, declaring the one variable outside the function to be a constant, as recommended, actually seemed to slow the code down a bit rather than speeding it up.

Comment: Random number generation is expensive. Try refactoring your code so that your random variates are calculated outside of your loops (I realize that it may not be easy in this case) to avoid function call overhead and benefit from vectorization. And don't use `tic`/`toc` to benchmark code unless you know how to warm up – use `timeit`.

Comment: In fact, it might be possible rewrite with no loops.

Comment: @horchler. Thanks for the input. Yes it is possible to remove some of the code from the loop and calculate a vector of random uniform outside the loop. As it is I am quite happy with the speed I got from Julia. I also like the structure of the code as it follows the Gibbs algorithm closely. I like it this way as, for me, it is easier to understand what the code does.